# Faster way to extract partial data from AdjacencyMatrix

Tags: performance-tuning

I am dealing with a lot of `Graph` objects. One task is to obtain an `Id` for each of them.
So I first used

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 4 -> 2, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5, 7 -> 2, 4 -> 7, 3 -> 8}];

GraphId[g_] := Module[{}, AdjacencyMatrix@CanonicalGraph@g]
FullForm@GraphId@g
```

which gives

```
SparseArray[
  Automatic,
  List[7,7],
  0,
  List[
    1,
    List[
      List[0,2,5,5,6,8,8,8],
      List[List[5],List[7],List[4],List[6],List[7],List[7],List[3],List[6]]
    ],
    List[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
  ]
]
```

I have to reduce this result to save space. The first approach is not to including `List[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` in the result. So I tried

```
ToData[g_] := (Last@ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString@FullForm@g, "Graph" -> "List"])[[1]]
GraphIdReduced[g_] := Module[{}, ToData@CanonicalGraph@g]
FullForm@GraphIdReduced@g
```

which gives

```
SparseArray[
  Automatic,
  List[7,7],
  0,
  List[
    1,
    List[
      List[0,2,5,5,6,8,8,8],
      List[List[5],List[7],List[4],List[6],List[7],List[7],List[3],List[6]]
    ],
    Pattern
  ]
]
```

Of course I can use the same approach to reduce the result much further.
But the problem is the above method is very slow.

```
gT=Table[g,{i,1,10^5}];
AbsoluteTiming[GraphId/@gT][[1]]
AbsoluteTiming[GraphIdReduced/@gT][[1]]
```

gives

```
1.185602
14.445625
```

, and for 10^6 times, the difference is `12.386422 vs 146.539146`.

Maybe this is because the string operations are slow, but I don't know how to do without it.
`Graph` and `SparseArray` are atomic object and I can't not use `Apply` to change their Head to `List` and then locate the contents I care about.

So how to extract some data from the above result more quickly?

In fact, the data I need is only

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the new-in-Version-10 properties `"RowPointers"` and `"ColumnIndices"` of a `SparseArray` object:

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 4 -> 2, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5, 7 -> 2, 4 -> 7, 3 -> 8}];
sa=AdjacencyMatrix@CanonicalGraph@g;

{sa["RowPointers"],Flatten[sa["ColumnIndices"]]}
(* {{0,2,5,5,6,8,8,8},{5,7,4,6,7,7,3,6}} *)
```

Or define a function

```
foo=Function[{s},{s@#,Flatten@s@#2}&@@{"RowPointers","ColumnIndices"}]
foo@sa
(* {{0,2,5,5,6,8,8,8},{5,7,4,6,7,7,3,6}} *)
```

Alternatively, you can  use the second part of `"NonzeroPositions"` instead of `"ColumnIndices"`:

```
{sa["RowPointers"],sa["NonzeroPositions"][[All,2]]}
(* {{0,2,5,5,6,8,8,8},{5,7,4,6,7,7,3,6}} *)
```

Note: There has been few additions to the still-undocumented `SparseArray` `"Properties"`, including `"RowPointers"` and `"ColumnIndices"` used above.

```
sa["Properties"]
(* {AdjacencyLists, Background, ColumnIndices, Density, NonzeroPositions,
    NonzeroValues, PatternArray, Properties, RowPointers} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "ID".

If you just need a unique signature, but you don't need to reconstruct the graph, use

```
Hash@CanonicalGraph[g]
```

If you need to reconstruct the graph, the minimal information needed is

```
{VertexCount[g], EdgeList@CanonicalGraph[g]}
```

You can then encode this into a more compact format depending on your needs. If all your graphs are connected, you can even drop the vertex count.

If you deal with undirected graphs, one compact representation is [the graph6 format](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/formats.html). Mathematica only supports the undirected version, but you can implement directed ones too.

```
ExportString[CanonicalGraph[g], "Graph6"]
(* ">>graph6<<FAhM_
" *)
```

Your graph takes only 5 ASCII characters in this representation.