# What are SparseArray Properties? How and when should they be used?

Tags: functions, sparse-arrays, undocumented, properties

A strange undocumented form of `SparseArray` is increasingly used in answers on this site:

```
SparseArray[(* data *)]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

What is this, and why would anyone want to use this?  Are there any other commands like it?

Answer (score 60):

#### Introduction

This post is long overdue as I have been repeatedly asked to explain code of mine containing these things.  As I see increased use of this construct by others perhaps it is *past due* also.

[`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) objects can behave as functions accepting certain arguments to return internal data or efficiently return data in certain forms.  These are known as Properties or Methods. They are not the only objects to have these; see for example [How to splice together several instances of InterpolatingFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction/19043#19043) for Methods of [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html).

As undocumented functionality these Properties are more likely to be [incompatibly changed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728/121) than documented functions and they could be removed entirely in future versions.  However they appear to have been stable (and extended) since the introduction of [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) itself so I feel this is still unlikely.

`SparseArray` is highly optimized therefore converting a tensor to a `SparseArray` and then using one of these Properties is often competitively fast, in many cases bettering seemingly more direct methods.  Before `Pick` was [optimized for packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11/121) in version 8 `SparseArray` was often the fasted method available outside of compilation therefore as a long-time version 7 user I made (and make) frequent use of these, most often `"AdjacencyLists"` or `"NonzeroPositions"`.  Many examples can be found with these searches:  [AdjacencyLists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=AdjacencyLists), [NonzeroPositions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=NonzeroPositions).

## Documentation

The primary Properties themselves may be listed by using `"Properties"` or (I believe) exhaustively with `"Methods"`; in *Mathematica* 7:

```
SparseArray[{1}]["Methods"]
```

> ```
> {"AdjacencyLists",   "Background",    "MethodInformation", "Methods", 
>  "NonzeroPositions", "NonzeroValues", "PatternArray",      "Properties"}
> ```

And in *Mathematica* 10.1:

```
SparseArray[{1}]["Methods"]
```

> ```
> {"AdjacencyLists", "Background",        "ColumnIndices", "Density",
>  "MatrixColumns",  "MethodInformation", "Methods",       "NonzeroPositions",
>  "NonzeroValues",  "PatternArray",      "Properties",    "RowPointers"}
> ```

There is limited internal documentation for these Properties in the form of hidden usage messages.  As shown below the non-string form may be used but in my opinion it is safer to use Strings.

```
sa = SparseArray[{1}];
sa["MethodInformation"@#] & ~Scan~ sa["Methods"]
```

> `SparseArray[data]@AdjacencyLists` gives the adjacency lists.
>
> `SparseArray[data]@Background` gives the background value.
>
> `SparseArray[data]@ColumnIndices` gives the column indices from the 
>   compressed sparse row data
>
> `SparseArray[data]@Density` fraction of all elements that are nonzero.
>
> `SparseArray[data]@MatrixColumns` gives the column indices for each
>   row of a matrix
>
> `SparseArray[data]@MethodInformation[method]` gives information about
>   a particular method.
>
> `SparseArray[data]@Methods[pat]` gives the list of methods matching
>   the string pattern pat.
>
> `SparseArray[data]@NonzeroPositions` gives the positions at which the
>   nonzero (different from background) elements occur.
>
> `SparseArray[data]@NonzeroValues` gives the values which occur at the
>   nonzero positions.
>
> `SparseArray[data]@PatternArray` gives the structural pattern template
>   SparseArray.
>
> `SparseArray[data]@Properties` gives the list of possible properties.
>
> `SparseArray[data]@RowPointers` gives the row pointers array from the
>   compressed sparse row data

Now in my own words:

#### NonzeroPositions

This Property returns the position of every *non-background* element in the sparse array.  The default background element is zero:

```
a = {{1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}};

sa0 = SparseArray[a];
sa0["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}
> ```

A different background may be specified:

```
sa1 = SparseArray[a, Automatic, 1];
sa1["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}
> ```

#### Background

This is simply the background element of the array, zero when unspecified or as specified during the construction the SparseArray;

```
sa0["Background"]
sa1["Background"]
```

> ```
> 0
>
> 1
> ```

#### NonzeroValues

These are the *non-background* values corresponding to the positions returned by `"NonzeroPositions"` returned as a flat list:

```
sa0["NonzeroValues"]
sa1["NonzeroValues"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}
>
> {0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0}
> ```

```
a ~Extract~ sa0["NonzeroPositions"]
a ~Extract~ sa1["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}
>
> {0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0}
> ```

#### AdjacencyLists

This is like `"NonzeroPositions"` given for every row in the array, except that single indexes are given as raw integers rater than in a list.

```
sa0["AdjacencyLists"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {3}, {1, 3}}
> ```

Unlike `"NonzeroPositions"` the List depth of the returned expression varies with tensor rank:

```
SparseArray[{1, 0, 2, 3, 0}]["AdjacencyLists"]

Array[Plus, {2, 3, 4}] ~Mod~ 3;
SparseArray[%]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 4}
>
> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}},
>  {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}}
> ```

#### PatternArray

This returns a modified `SparseArray` object that represents an expression in which only the background elements remain and all others are replaced with `_` ([`Blank[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)). [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) may be used to convert it to a standard `List` tensor.

```
sa0["PatternArray"] // Normal

sa1["PatternArray"] // Normal
```

> ```
> {{_, 0, _}, {0, 0, _}, {_, 0, _}}
>
> {{1, _, _}, {_, _, 1}, {_, _, 1}}
> ```

#### Density

The fraction of all *non-background* elements in the sparse array as a Real number:

```
Count[a, Except[0], {2}] / Length@Flatten@a // N

sa0["Density"]
```

> ```
> 0.555556
>
> 0.555556
> ```

```
Count[a, Except[1], {2}] / Length@Flatten@a // N

sa1["Density"]
```

> ```
> 0.666667
>
> 0.666667
> ```

#### MatrixColumns

This appears to be identical to AdjacencyLists for a two dimensional sparse array and inapplicable otherwise, returning unevaluated.  Not listed in the shorter `"Properties"` list this Method is perhaps unfinished or deprecated.

#### ColumnIndices and RowPointers

These newer Properties allow one to extract two internal structures of a `SparseArray` object without resorting to destructuring methods.  Observe the alignment:

```
sa1 // InputForm

sa1 /@ {"RowPointers", "ColumnIndices"}
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 4, 6}, {{2}, {3}, {1}, {2}, {1}, {2}}}
>
> SparseArray[Automatic, {3, 3}, 1, 
>  {1, {{0, 2, 4, 6}, {{2}, {3}, {1}, {2}, {1}, {2}}},
>    {0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0}}]
> ```

These internal structures are fairly complex and are the subject of another Q&A:

- [How to interpret the FullForm of a SparseArray?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18081/121)

Leonid Shifrin summarizes them as:

> - (RowPointers) gives a total number of nonzero (non-default) elements as we add rows
> - (ColumnIndices) gives positions of non-zero elements in all rows

kguler makes use of both in answer to [Faster way to extract partial data from AdjacencyMatrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58933/faster-way-to-extract-partial-data-from-adjacencymatrix/58936#58936).

## Application

- As briefly noted in the introduction `SparseArray` may be chosen for performance benefits.
- In some cases is one of the most clean ways to write a particular operation.
- When a `SparseArray` is returned by a System function it can be far superior to work with its Properties than to convert it to a [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) array and (re)compute them externally.

(This section will be extended with multiple examples when I have sufficient time to do them rigorously.)

---

#### Related:

- [How to interpret the FullForm of a SparseArray?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18081/121)
- [SparseArray row operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31908/121)
- [Leonid's SparseArray destructuring tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596134/efficient-alternative-to-outer-on-sparse-arrays-in-mathematica/8609071#8609071)

Comment: +1, I known the `"NonzeroPositions"` yesterday from this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83602/how-to-find-all-the-positions-of-max-value-of-a-list-efficiently/83609#83609). However, I cannot find the documentation. So I just use it. Thanks for sharing the documentation:-)

Comment: @ShutaoTang That was the post that finally compelled me to write this.  When I was practically the sole loony using it I didn't feel *too* bad making people ask, but as more and more people start using it documentation is *required.*

Comment: BTW, @Mr.Wizard, I'd like to know why the `WRI` didn't document these properties. In fact, these properties are very useful.

Comment: @Shutao I would like to know too.  [Here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Jan/msg00815.html) I asked if they were documented and Oliver Ruebenkoenig wrote: *"Unfortunately they are not, but I filed a suggestion for them to be 
documented. However, I can not say when/if this will be approved."*  That was more than four years ago.

Comment: Anyway, @Mr.Wizard, I learned much from your answers.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is a great post with additional great links, Thanks Mr. Wizard!

Comment: There's also `sa0["NonzeroPositions"[2]]` which gives the first 2 non-zero positions.

Comment: @Silvia That syntax does not appear to work for me in version 10.1.  Do you know when it was added?  How did you learn of it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [It works in my 11.0](http://i.stack.imgur.com/llg6L.png). I found it recently by random trying.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard +1 ! this answer partly helped me today

Answer (score 5):

In addition, there is `TreatRepeatedEntries` which allows for additive assembly as used in [How to speed up this SparseArray construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212692/how-to-speed-up-this-sparsearray-construction/212698#212698) in an answer provided Henrik Schumacher.

The core code, please refer to the Q&A of the above link for the full context.

```
 MySparseArray[R_Rule, dims_?VectorQ, fun_: Total, background_: 0] :=
 With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   SetSystemOptions[
    "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> fun}],
   SparseArray[R, dims, background],
   SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
  ]
```