# Replace non-zero elements with symbol

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement, formatting

I have a very large matrix (tensor) in Mathematica with some zero and non-zero elements.  I am interested in replacing the non-zero elements with some symbol or a 1 so that it is easier to view the entire object.

I would include my code but there is a lot of preamble so here is an analogue of what I would like to work on:

```
{{{{0, -a Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], -c Sqrt[a^2 + c^2]}, {-a Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], 
 0, 0}, {-c Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], 0, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, 
 0}, {0, -2 a^2, -2 a c}, {0, -2 a c, -2 c^2}}}, {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}}
```

and I would like to output something like:

```
{{{{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 
 1}}}, {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}}
```

Comment: Try `SparseArray[array]["PatternArray"] // Normal`.

Comment: @J.M. it replaces non-zeros with blanks... And it looks like black magic

Comment: @BlacKow, well, you can always do `Verbatim[_] -> 1` if need be. :)

Comment: `Map[Boole@*PossibleZeroQ, array, {4}]`

Comment: Cross-ref: [What are SparseArray Properties? How and when should they be used?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83721/106)

Answer (score 5):

I propose the use of [`ArrayComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayComponents.html) and [`Unitize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unitize.html):

```
array = {{{{0, -a Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], -c Sqrt[a^2 + c^2]},
           {-a Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], 0, 0}, {-c Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], 0, 0}}},
         {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -2 a^2, -2 a c}, {0, -2 a c, -2 c^2}}},
         {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}};

array // ArrayComponents // Unitize
```

> ```
> {{{{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}},
>  {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}},
>  {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}}
> ```

For the purpose of visualization you may also be interested to know that [`MatrixPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html) and [`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html) will handle symbolic element in the following way:

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -2 a^2, -2 a c}, {0, -2 a c, -2 c^2}} // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

Therefore you could visualize your complete array with something like:

```
array /. m_?MatrixQ :> ArrayPlot[m] // Grid
```

[image]

Other possibilities exist if you have different needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
mat = {{{{0, -a Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], -c Sqrt[a^2 + c^2]}, {-a Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], 0, 0},
          {-c Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], 0, 0}}}, 
        {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -2 a^2, -2 a c}, {0, -2 a c, -2 c^2}}}, 
        {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}}
```

You can use

```
f1 = Replace[#, Except[0 | _List] -> 1, Infinity] &;
f2 = SparseArray[SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"] -> 1, Dimensions[#]] &;
f3 = Block[{f}, SetAttributes[f, Listable]; f[0] = 0; f[_] := 1; f@#] &;


f1 @ mat
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Equal @@ (Through[{f1, f2, f3}@mat])
```

> True

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code for almost a similar purpose. Hope it also helps you out:

```
mtx = {{{{0, -a Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], -c Sqrt[a^2 + c^2]}, {-a Sqrt[
    a^2 + c^2], 0, 0}, {-c Sqrt[a^2 + c^2], 0, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, 
  0}, {0, -2 a^2, -2 a c}, {0, -2 a c, -2 c^2}}}, {{{0, 0, 0}, {0,
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}};

  {Rw, Cl, rw, cl} = Dimensions[mtx];

  Do[
    If[
    mtx[[k, 1, i, j]] =!= 0,
    mtx[[k, 1, i, j]] = 1
    ],
    {k, Rw},
    {i, rw},
    {j, cl}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace) that only works at one level instead of all of them (as in @kglr's answer):

```
Replace[mat, Except[0]->1, {ArrayDepth[mat]}] //TeXForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$