# How to find position of non-zero elements in SparseArray without converting to a dense object

Tags: sparse-arrays

## Overview

So I have a `SparseArray`, sparse, constructed from a list of rules, with the dimension options. Given a row, I want to know *where* the values are non-zero. Finding what those values are is easy, but where is harder...

#### How the `SparseArray` was made

```
listOfRules = {{1,1} -> 3, {4,30} -> 4 ... };
sparse = SparseArray[listOfRules,{n,n}];
```

#### Find non-zero values in a row

```
Select[sparse[[rowNumber]],#!=0&]
```

#### Attempts to find position of nonzero elements of a row

The obvious solution is not to work with a sparse array

```
Flatten[Position[Normal[sparse[[rowNumber]]],n_Integer/;n>0]]
```

Unfortunalely

```
Position[sparse[[rowNumber]],n_Integer/;n>0]
```

does not work.

Interestingly the pure function *works* for with the function `Select`, but not `Position`, e.g.

```
Position[Normal[sparse[[rowNumber]]],#!=0]
```

returns nothing. Whereas the pattern *works* for the function `Position` but not `Select`

```
Select[sparse[[rowNumber]], n_Integer /; n > 0]
```

Neither `Keys` or `Values` work either... which I thought might, since it is built off a list of rules.

Oh and the obvious

```
Select[sparse[[rowNumber]],aNumber]
Position[sparse[[rowNumber,aNumber]
```

do not work either, although I know that there is an element with that value because

```
 Select[sparse[[rowNumber]],#!=0&]
```

tells me that they do exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*Posting as an answer since it seems too long to be a comment.*)

The answer to your question is in [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83722/34008) of this question ["What are SparseArray Properties? How and when should they be used?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83721/34008).

One of the examples in [the referred answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83722/34008) is:

```
a = {{1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}};
sa0 = SparseArray[a];
sa0["NonzeroPositions"]

(* {{1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}} *)
```

Note that "NonzeroPositions" returns the position of every *non-background* element in the sparse array.

Another option is to use:

```
sa0["AdjacencyLists"]
```

Comment: It will be obvious for people familiar with sparse arrays, but it may be good to point out that this actually gives the positions of non-default elements.  The default element may be something other than zero.

Comment: @Szabolcs Right. I was thinking to point out that, but it was emphasized in the linked [answer of Mr.Wizard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83722/34008). I added a note...