# Support for low-complexity (compressible) lists

Tags: memory, data-structures, compression

By "low-complexity list" I mean a list like the following:

```
lcl = {17, 17, 17, 17, 17,
       21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
       11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11}
```

It contains 20 elements, but only 3 distinct values, and furthermore, these values occur in homogeneous blocks.

---

More formally, one can represent any list<sup>1</sup> with a "run-length encoding".  For example:

```
rle[list_] := Transpose[{First[#], Length[#]} & /@ Split[list]]
```

...or, if you prefer, this slightly fancier version:

```
rle[list_, equal_:SameQ, representative_:First] := 
    Transpose[{representative[#], Length[#]} & /@ Split[list, equal]]
```

---

For the list `lcl` shown earlier, `rle[lcl]` is

```
{{17, 21, 11}, {5, 8, 7}}
```

For the sake of this discussion, let's define the "compressibility" of a list `list` as the ratio

```
Length[list]/Length[Flatten[rle[list]]]
```

Low-complexity lists are therefore those for which this compressibility measure is substantially greater than 1.

The compressibility of the list `lcl` shown above is (only) 20/6 = 3.33.  In contrast, I need to work with lists whose compressibilities lie in the range $10^4-10^5$.

---

**Q:** Does *Mathematica* provide any support (data structure, functions) for representing such "low-complexity lists" more compactly, while still being able to use them as lists?

---

If `x` is a numeric low-complexity list, as here defined, `Differences[x]` is sparse (even though `x` isn't).  For example, applying `Differences` to the example above yields

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

That said, I can't think of a way to take advantage of *Mathematica*'s excellent `SparseArray` in this context.

---

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, I'm asking whether in the vast *Mathematica* universe there already exists support for this sort of beast.  I just don't want to reinvent wheels, especially for something like this, which would be far better implemented at a lower level than "user-space".

By far, the operation I'm most interested in is indexing (i.e. `Part`), especially complex indexing form, such as indexing with a list of indices, or with ranges (e.g. `1000;;1999`).

For simple indexing, I could base a home-grown solution on this sort of thing

```
FirstPosition[..., i_ /; # < i] &
```

...where `...` is a placeholder for an internal data structure (part of the low-complexity list representation) that holds the positions of the elements that is different from their predecessors.

I'm also interested in `Map` and friends (`Table`, `Scan`, etc.), but much less.

---

The very beginning of the implementation I alluded to before could be as follows (but this providing full support for `Part`/alone would require considerably more code, I think).

```
lcList[l_List] := Module[
  {
     values
   , counts
   , pivots
  },
    (* the rle function is defined earlier in this post *)
    {values, counts} = rle[l]
  ; pivots = 1 + Accumulate @ counts
  ; lcList[<|"values" -> values,
             "pivots" -> pivots,
             "ceiling" -> Last @ pivots|>]
]

lcList /: Length[lcList[a_Association]] := a["ceiling"] - 1

lcList /: Part[lcList[a_Association], i_Integer] :=
   a["values"][[First@FirstPosition[a["pivots"], j_ /; i < j]]] /;
   0 < i < a["ceiling"]
```

Then, with the list `lcl` shown at the top of this post,

```
rleLcl = lcList[lcl]

rleLcl[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[rleLcl]]
```

> ```
> {17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11}
> ```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Well, not *any* list, but rather, any list of elements such that, for any two of them, `a` and `b`, we have an adequate equality predicate `equal[a, b]`.</sup>

Comment: What operations do you typically want to do with these lists?

Comment: Maybe  Tally[list]?

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing *Mathematica* implementation of what you're asking. Your `lcList` seems like a good start. Make sure your arrays are- and stay packed. Searching for appropriate `pivots` can be compiled. If you need to access parts of same list many times, then maybe storing `pivots` as some kind of search tree would be justifiable.

Comment: Flatten[Tally /@ Split[lcl], 1]

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: Interesting idea, but when I time it I find that it is ~2x slower than the more pedestrian-looking `{First[#], Length[#]} & /@ Split[lcl]`.

Comment: @kjo You are right. I have also noticed the performance drawback. The effect even grows with increasing length of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I do not believe there is built-in functionality for the data form you describe.

However [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) comes close.  Here's an example.

```
in = {17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
   11};

sa = SparseArray @ Differences @ Prepend[in, 0];
p = sa["AdjacencyLists"]
v = in[[p]]

f = Quiet@*Interpolation[
    Join[{p - 1, RotateRight@v}\[Transpose], {{Last@p, Last@v}}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0];

in === Array[f, Length@in]
```

> ```
> {1, 6, 14}
>
> {17, 21, 11}
>
> True
> ```

So this gives a function `f` which returns the element of `in` for a given index.

We can also pull spans from the `SparseArray` (assigned to `sa`) like this:

```
in[[10 ;; 15]]

Accumulate @ sa[[10 ;; 15]] + f[10]
```

> ```
> {21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 11}
>
> {21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 11}
> ```

For large extractions this is much faster than using the `InterpolatingFunction` (`f`).  Using the code above but starting with:

```
SeedRandom[0];
in = Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ RandomInteger[{1, 99}, {5000, 2}];
```

Then:

```
(r1 = Accumulate@sa[[100000 ;; 150000]] + f[100000];)   // RepeatedTiming
(r2 = f @ Range[100000, 150000];)                       // RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {0.000696, Null}
>
> {0.0527, Null}
>
> True
> ```

Comment: I love how you managed to make good use of "discrete integration" (aka `Accumulate`), thereby exploiting the "discrete differentiation" (aka `Differences`) aspect of the problem.  Beautiful stuff.  That said, probably it would be good to point out explicitly in your answer that it works only for lists of numeric scalars.  I am unfamiliar with `Interpolation` and with the `"AdjacencyLists"` property (for which I have yet to find any official documentation) of `SparseArrays`, so I'm still digesting your answer, but one detail that bothers me a bit...

Comment: ...is the 0 sentinel (in `SparseArray @ Differences @ Prepend[in, 0]`): what happens, for example, when `in` begins with 0?  Is 0 dictated by `SparseArray`'s assumptions/defaults/implementation details?  Or could you use, say, `First[in] - 1`?

Comment: BTW, I found your https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/what-are-sparsearray-properties-how-and-when-should-they-be-used...  Thanks!

Comment: @kjo Hah, I didn't expect to get an Accept with this, but thanks.  You're right, I didn't consider zero appearing anywhere in the input list and I didn't handle it.  I'll try to fix that later.  The background of a `SparseArray` can be changed by using its third parameter but that by itself won't fix that problem.

Comment: After I thought about it some more I realized that the value of the sentinel is orthogonal to the `SparseArray` background value, because you're using `SparseArray` on the differences of the original list, not the list itself.  Also, I think that using `First[in] + c` (for some reasonable non-zero constant `c`) is the way to go for the sentinel.

Answer (score 4):

```
 {First[#], Length[#]}& /@ 
 Split[{17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11}]
```

(*

{{17, 5}, {21, 8}, {11, 7}}

*)

```
{First[#], Length[#]}& /@ 
Split[ {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

(*

{{0, 4}, {4, 1}, {0, 7}, {-10, 1}, {0, 6}}

*)

@J.M. points out that it is simpler to use `Split` than `SplitBy`.

Comment: Have you just reinvented `Tally`?

Comment: Not if there are multiple sequences having the same value.

Comment: It's not Tally. Check the second example.

Comment: Ah yes... if there are multiple sequences having the same value, then Tally is not what the OP seeks.

Comment: `Composition[Through, {First, Length}] /@ Split[list]` should also do the trick; no need for `SplitBy[]`.

Comment: So we have reinvented the Run-Length Encoding implementation from Wolfram MathWorld - see [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Run-LengthEncoding.html)

Comment: Hah!  Yes!  A very simple idea indeed.

Answer (score 3):

1. Transform unique numbers to digits base n (length of unique numbers)
2. Transform original list to digits base n
3. Construct an integer from the list of it's digits base n

Using integer instead of a list of numbers uses much less memory. (1 : 10)

In:

```
Clear[xs, ys, number, rules]
ToNumber[xs_] := Module[{uniques, base, digits, rules, number},
  uniques  = Union[xs];
  base = Length[uniques];
  digits = Range[0, base - 1];
  rules = Thread[Rule[uniques, digits]];
  number = FromDigits[(xs /. rules), base];
  {number, base, Map[Reverse, rules]}
  ]

xs = RandomChoice[Range[0, 19]*5, 10^2];
{number, base, rules} = ToNumber[xs]

ys = IntegerDigits[number, base] /. rules

(* Test *)
xs == ys

(* Memory *)
xs // ByteCount
number // ByteCount
```

Out:

```
{60, 75, 60, 20, 70, 30, 5, 5, 15, 90, 75, 90, 0, 50, 35, 80, 30, 15, \
25, 70, 65, 90, 5, 25, 35, 20, 65, 40, 80, 15, 20, 40, 45, 95, 50, \
70, 55, 35, 5, 70, 10, 90, 55, 85, 25, 25, 95, 90, 85, 20, 80, 55, \
45, 35, 75, 25, 30, 5, 5, 30, 65, 80, 25, 85, 35, 35, 50, 75, 0, 20, \
65, 85, 40, 35, 25, 55, 65, 20, 75, 60, 0, 50, 60, 80, 10, 35, 5, 5, \
5, 75, 60, 65, 25, 10, 10, 30, 25, 55, 90, 90}

{810066090674088052770306597191253060527186521556149860642933055414395\
7285417316417930562947049000100525456920489251180883335404778, 
20, 
{0 -> 0, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 10, 3 -> 15, 4 -> 20, 5 -> 25, 6 -> 30, 7 -> 35, 
  8 -> 40, 9 -> 45, 10 -> 50, 11 -> 55, 12 -> 60, 13 -> 65, 14 -> 70, 
  15 -> 75, 16 -> 80, 17 -> 85, 18 -> 90, 19 -> 95}}

 {60, 75, 60, 20, 70, 30, 5, 5, 15, 90, 75, 90, 0, 50, 35, 80, 30, 15, \
25, 70, 65, 90, 5, 25, 35, 20, 65, 40, 80, 15, 20, 40, 45, 95, 50, \
70, 55, 35, 5, 70, 10, 90, 55, 85, 25, 25, 95, 90, 85, 20, 80, 55, \
45, 35, 75, 25, 30, 5, 5, 30, 65, 80, 25, 85, 35, 35, 50, 75, 0, 20, \
65, 85, 40, 35, 25, 55, 65, 20, 75, 60, 0, 50, 60, 80, 10, 35, 5, 5, \
5, 75, 60, 65, 25, 10, 10, 30, 25, 55, 90, 90}

True
936
96
```