# Get the dimensions from the SparseArray properties

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, data-structures

In the sparse matrix, we have a list of properties: specified elements, dimension, default, and density. I am interested in getting this data without calculating them again.
 For an example, the following sparse matrix has dimension 3*3

```
s = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}]
```

[image]

I can calculate the `s` dimension by

```
Dimensions[s]
```

but I look for option to get this information from `s` properties

Comment: ok, fair enough

Comment: I have asked a new question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### "Properties"

The listed `"Properties"` does not include dimensions

```
s["Properties"]
(* {"AdjacencyLists", "Background", "ColumnIndices", "Density", \
"MatrixColumns", "NonzeroValues", "PatternArray", "Properties", \
"RowPointers"} *)
```

You can read more about `SparseArray` "Properties" in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83722/10397).

[`Dimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html) works, as you stated,

```
Dimensions[s]
(* {3, 3} *)
```

And there is also `` SparseArray`SparseArrayDimensions ``,

> twice as fast as `Dimension`, probably alone due to the redirect

based on the estimations by @HenrikSchumacher

```
SparseArray`SparseArrayDimensions[s]
(* {3, 3} *)
```

Following the lead from @JasonB. in his answer to a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179165/10397), one could define the desired effect by

```
Unprotect[SparseArray];
(s_SparseArray)["Dimensions"] := SparseArray`SparseArrayDimensions[s];
Protect[SparseArray];
```

---

### Side note:

The [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) reveals

```
FullForm[s]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Where the second element is the dimensions, and from the documentation under *Possible Issues* you can find

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
HoldPattern[spart[SparseArray[stuff___], p_]] := {stuff}[[p]]

spart[s, 2]
(* {3, 3} *)
```

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko Just a short note: `Dimensions[s]` does not compute anything. Quite likely, it calls `SparseArray`SparseArrayDimensions` and that one just _reads_ some values from the internal structure of a sparse array. A bit to my surprise, `SparseArray`SparseArrayDimensions` is twice as fast as `Dimension`, probably alone due to the redirect I mentioned. It does not matter though, as the timings are  of order `3. 10^-7`, hence neglectible for nearly all purposes.