# Get the number of specified elements from the SparseArray properties

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

In the sparse matrix, we have a list of properties: specified elements, dimension, default, and density. I am interested in getting this data without calculating them again. For an example, the following sparse matrix has four specified elements.

```
s = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}]
```

I can calculate the number of specified elements of `s` by

```
Length@s["NonzeroValues"]
```

but I look for an option to get this information from `s` properties

Comment: From the previous question, you know all the properties available. The length of "NonzeroValues" is not available, but you can calculate it, as you just did. Why is `Length@s["NonzeroValues"]` not an acceptable solution? I'm afraid it is not clear what fundamentally is the question you are asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP already gave the optimal solution.

Comment: At least if `s well-formatted (e.g., if `SparseArray`SparseArraySortedQ[s]` returns `True`), `s["RowPointers"][[-1]]` is a second possibility. But `Length[s["NonzeroValues"]]` is much safer.

Comment: Also `Length` won't compute anything. `s["NonzeroValues"]` is a basic constitutent of a sparse array. Within the internal data type for sparse arrays (`MSparseSparseArray`), `s["NonzeroValues"]` is stored as a dense array (`MTensor`). The length (and dimensions) of a dense array are also stored in each `MTensor` object, so `Length` just _reads off_ a value of a field of the `MTensor`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Shouldn't that be a clear sign that OP should self-answer and wait to see if a better answer comes along, rather than a close vote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want a convenient accessor for the nonzero value count, which seems reasonable.  You could define your own function, but you'd like to get it from properties instead.

I think this is a good use case for adding your own definition to a system function, which is allowed by the language.  You just need to unprotect the symbol first,

```
Unprotect[SparseArray];
(s_SparseArray)["NonzeroValueCount"] := Length[s["NonzeroValues"]];
Protect[SparseArray];
```

It can be accessed like any other property now,

```
s["NonzeroValueCount"]
(* 4 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to what you have already considered there is the [property](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83722/121) `"Density"`:

```
slen = #["Density"] Times @@ Dimensions[#] &;

SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}] // slen
```

> ```
> 4.
> ```

Comment: That seems a very convoluted way around `Length@#["NonzeroValues"]&`.

Comment: @rhermans Perhaps, but it is *faster* should that be important.  I'll add an example. EDIT No, I'm wrong.  I thought I'd looked at this before; it's not.  Well there's egg on my face. :^)

Comment: `SparseArray\`SparseArrayDimensions` for speed then.

Comment: @rhermans I don't believe I've ever used that function before; let me try it. Thanks!

Comment: @rhermans Still not as fast as the direct way.  :-/

Comment: I'd be surprise if there were a faster way then `Length@s["NonzeroValues"]`...

Comment: @Henrik I saw your comment after posting and it makes perfect sense now.  I think what I was remembering that nonzero-*Positions* is a nontrival operation and would take measurable time, and confused that with *values*.  I rarely if ever use `"NonzeroValues"` but `"NonzeroPositions"` was a very common tool for me in v7 before `Pick` was optimized.