# Find longest sequence of zeros in list

Tags: list-manipulation

How it is possible to find the length of the longest sequence of zeros in list

```
{1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1}
```

which is equal to 4 in the sample list above

Comment: Another way: `SequenceCases[seq, {p : Repeated[0]} :> Length[{p}]] // Max` (too similar to others, and to docs,  to post as answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming it is a binary sequence, one way is to look at all the differences in the positions of the 1s and take the largest:

```
seq = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};
Max[Differences[Position[seq, 1]]] - 1
4
```

As pointed out in the comments by jkuczm and Hector, this will fail if the longest sequence of zeros occurs at either the start or the end. This can be fixed by surrounding the sequence with 1s:

```
Max[Differences[Position[Flatten@{1, seq, 1}, 1]]] - 1
```

Comment: I must say this is an awful lot faster than using patterns! `0.000115` seconds for this vs `0.221` for my implementation of patterns in a list of 500 integers.

Comment: There are more assumptions for this to work. You need at least two `1`s and longest sequence of zeros can't start at first element. So it'll fail e.g. for `{1, 0, 0, 0}` or `{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}`.

Comment: The assumptions are easy to satisfy: `Max[Differences[Position[Join[{1,1},seq], 1]]] - 1`

Comment: @Hector it still fails for `{1, 0, 0, 0}`. I guess that correct assumption is not that "longest sequence of zeros can't start at first element" as I've written before, but that sequence of zeros, to be counted, should be surrounded by `1`s. So `1` should be added at beginning and at end as in current version of [answer by kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179195/14303): `Max[Differences[Position[Join[{1}, seq, {1}], 1]]] - 1`.

Answer (score 15):

```
Max@FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #1 + 1, 0] &, 0, seq]
```

Answer (score 13):

If you need speed and are only using packable arrays you could use a compiled function. Function generator returning compiled functions, performing desired operation can look like this:

```
compileLongestSeqLen // ClearAll
compileLongestSeqLen[
  {type_, rank_Integer /; rank >= 1}, inSeqQ_, opts : OptionsPattern@Compile
] := Compile[{{list, type, rank}},
  Module[{len = 0, longest = 0},
    Do[
      If[inSeqQ@x,
        ++len;
      (* else *),
        If[len > longest, longest = len];
        len = 0;
      ]
      ,
      {x, list}
    ];
    If[len > longest, longest = len];
    longest
  ],
  opts
]
```

Let's compile function finding length of longest sequence of zeros in list of integers:

```
jkuczm = compileLongestSeqLen[{_Integer, 1}, # === 0 &,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
]
```

To compare efficiency let's define functions from other answers:

```
alan = Max@FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #1 + 1, 0] &, 0, #] &;
billSHect1 = Max[Differences[Position[Flatten@{1, #, 1}, 1]]] - 1 &;
billSHect2 = Max[Differences[Position[Join[{1}, #, {1}], 1]]] - 1 &;
carlL = # /. {___, a : Longest[Repeated[0]], ___} :> Length[{a}] &;
chyanog1 = GroupBy[Split[#], First -> Length, Max][0] &;
chyanog2 = (# // Split // Select[MemberQ[0]] // Map[Length] // Max) &;
joe = (SortBy[Split[#], Length] // Last // Length) &;
kglr1 = Max[Differences@PositionIndex[Join[{1}, #, {1}]][1]] - 1 &;
kglr2 = Max[Length /@ Split@Accumulate[Join[{1}, #, {1}]]] - 1 &;
maxZeros[a_List] := Max[Append[# - 1, Length@a] - Prepend[#, 0]] &@SparseArray[a]["AdjacencyLists"]
okkes = (Length /@ Split[#] // Max) &;
```

Timings for single large list:

```
SeedRandom@0
test = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10^6];

(*carlLRes = carlL@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming*)   (*too slow*)
chyanog2Res = chyanog2@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming (*{0.62,  44510360}*)
(*joeRes = joe@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming*)       (*incorrect results*)
chyanog1Res = chyanog1@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming (*{0.36,  64019000}*)
billSRes1 = billSHect1@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming (*{0.33, 119935248}*)
billSRes2 = billSHect2@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming (*{0.31, 119934952}*)
kglr2Res = kglr2@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming       (*{0.26,  75941464}*)
(*okkesRes = okkes@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming*)   (*incorrect results*)
kglr1Res = kglr1@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming       (*{0.11,  44568024}*)
alanRes = alan@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming         (*{0.063, 40008744}*)
mrWizRes = maxZeros@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming    (*{0.0273 17126232}*)
jkuczmRes = jkuczm@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming     (*{0.0047,      56}*)

(*carlLRes ===*) chyanog2Res === (*joeRes ===*) chyanog1Res === billSRes1 === billSRes2 === kglr2Res === (*okkesRes ===*) kglr1Res === alanRes === mrWizRes === jkuczmRes
(* True *)
```

Timings for multiple lists:

```
SeedRandom@0
test = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {100, 10^5}];

(*carlLRes=carlL/@test;//MaxMemoryUsed//RepeatedTiming*)           (*too slow*)
chyanog2Res = chyanog2 /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming (*{6.3,  84491416}*)
(*joeRes = joe /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming*)       (*incorrect results*)
chyanog1Res = chyanog1 /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming (*{3.46, 86460488}*)
billSRes1 = billSHect1 /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming (*{3.29, 92106568}*)
kglr2Res = kglr2 /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming       (*{2.68, 87630888*)
(*okkesRes = okkes /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming*)   (*incorrect results*)
kglr1Res = kglr1 /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming       (*{1.12, 84780440}*)
alanRes = alan /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming         (*{0.379, 2409680}*)
billSRes2 = billSHect2 /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming (*{0.24,  2400320}*)
mrWizRes = maxZeros /@ test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming    (*{0.22, 81755512}*)
jkuczmRes = jkuczm@test; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming        (*{0.030, 1602456}*)

(*carlLRes ===*) chyanog2Res === (*joeRes ===*) chyanog1Res === billSRes1 === kglr2Res === (*okkesRes ===*) kglr1Res === alanRes === billSRes2 === mrWizRes === jkuczmRes
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 9):

This is relatively straightforward using patterns.

```
l /. {___, a : Longest[Repeated[0]], ___} :> Length[{a}]
```

That is, name list `a` the `Longest` list of `Repeated` zeroes bounded on either side by anything not a zero (the `___` matches none or more of anything), and then get the `Length` of that list `a`.

The [Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html) documentation will help you a lot here.

Answer (score 6):

```
GroupBy[Split[seq], First -> Length, Max][0]
```

or

```
seq // Split // Select[MemberQ[0]] // Map[Length] // Max
```

Answer (score 4):

```
f1 = Max[Differences @ PositionIndex[Join[{1}, #, {1}]][1]] - 1&;
f2 = Max[Length /@ Split @ Accumulate[Join[{1}, #, {1}]]] - 1 &;


list1 = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};
list2 = {0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};

f1 @ list1
```

> 4

```
f1 @ list2
```

> 6

```
f2 @ list1
```

> 4

```
f2 @ list2
```

> 6

Comment: First implementation, as in bill s answer, will fail if there are less than two `1`s. Both will fail if longest sequence of zeros starts with first element.

Comment: Thank you again @jkuczm. Was able to salvage both  with a minor tweak.

Comment: I think that `f1` is now correct. `f2` fails if there's `0` as first element, but it's not part of longest sequence of `0`s, e.g. `f2@{0, 1, 0, 0} (* 3 *)`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Mathematica user, but in several other languages I generalized this to (run-length encoding)

```
rle(x==0)
```

which eliminates the requirement that x be only 1 or zero.

---

(**EDIT** by corey979)

As per [Karsten's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179187/find-longest-sequence-of-zeros-in-list#comment468794_179285), the `rle` can be implemented in MMA as

```
RunLengthEncode[x_List] := {First[#], Length[#]}& /@ Split[x]
```

Comment: Run-lenght encoding implemented in the Wolfram Language: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Run-LengthEncoding.html

Comment: Or `Tally /@ Split[x] // Catenate` (but can we adapt to OP question?)

Answer (score 3):

At least in *Mathematica* 10.1 we can improve on bill s's solution by an order of magnitude using [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) [Properties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83721/121) as I did for [Find subsequences of consecutive integers inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121#23623).

My proposal:

```
maxZeros[a_List] := 
  Max[Append[# - 1, Length@a] - Prepend[#, 0]] & @ SparseArray[a]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

Timings:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

f1[a_] := Max[Differences[Position[Flatten@{1, a, 1}, 1]]] - 1

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, maxZeros}, RandomInteger[1, #] &]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Max @ Map[Length] @ SequenceSplit[list, {1 ..}]
```

4

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};
```

Using `Split` and `Cases`:

```
Max@Cases[s : {0 ..} :> Length@s]@Split[#] &@list

(*4*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
Max@SequenceCases[list, s : {0 ..} :> Length@s]

(*4*)
```