# Indices of nonzero rows in a sparse array

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

Given $A\!\in\!\mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}$ stored as `a=SparseArray[{...},{m,n}]`, how can I obtain the list of all indices $i\!\in\!\{1,\ldots,m\}$ for which the $i$-th row in $A$ is nonzero?

One option is `DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Transpose[a]["ColumnIndices"]`. Is there a nicer way, or is this optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Random`Private`PositionsOf[Unitize[Differences[a["RowPointers"]]], 1]
```

A timing example:

```
n = 100000;
m = 6000000;
a = AdjacencyMatrix@RandomGraph[{n, m}];
a[[RandomInteger[{1, n}, 1000], All]] = 0;

r = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Transpose[a]["ColumnIndices"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r1 = Random`Private`PositionsOf[Unitize[Differences[a["RowPointers"]]], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Sort[r] == r1
```

> 0.579587
>
> 0.002103
>
> True

## Edit

The undocumented function `` Random`Private`PositionsOf `` may be replaced by the following compiled function.

```
PositionsOfInteger = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {x, _Integer}},
   Block[{b, i = 0},
    b = Table[0, {Length[a]}];
    Do[If[Compile`GetElement[a, j] == x, b[[++i]] = j], {j, 1, 
      Length[a]}];
    If[i > 0, b[[1 ;; i]], Most[{0}]]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Indeed, this turns out to be even a bit faster:

```
r2 = PositionsOfInteger[Unitize[Differences[a["RowPointers"]]], 1]; //
   AbsoluteTiming // First
r1 == r2
```

> 0.001647
>
> True

Comment: What does `"ColumnIndices"` do? In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/what-are-sparsearray-properties-how-and-when-should-they-be-used), it says "gives the row pointers array from the compressed sparse row data", but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: And what is this `Random`Private`PositionsOf`? I can't find these commands in the documentation.

Comment: In a nutshell, one has these relations (both expression evaluate to `True`): `Flatten[a["ColumnIndices"]] == a["NonzeroPositions"][[All, 2]]` and 
`Prepend[Accumulate[Total[Unitize[a], {2}]], 0] == a["RowPointers"]`.

Comment: There is no documentation on ``Random`Private`PositionsOf``; it is an undocumented funtion. ``Random`Private`PositionsOf[#, 0] &`` does essentially the same as `Flatten[Position[#, 0]] &` - but it is ten times faster.

Comment: If these functions are undocumented, this means they are still in development? So when they are finally released as part of a new version of Mathematica (presumably under different names), the old calls to them will not work? When do you think they will become an official part of Mathematica. Is it safe to include such code in an article now?

Comment: Well, _everything_ in _Mathematica_ has a nonvanishing risk to be invalidated by future versions. However, for symbols in the ``"System`"`` context, this risk is rather small. While there are several prominent examples of undocumented symbols that appear to have been ''stable'' for several major realeases, the risk of future changes of these symbols is certainly much higher. This is why I added a compiled function `PositionsOfInteger` as substitute for ``Random`Private`PositionsOf``.