# Bottom-most left-most entries in a sparse array

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, associations, sparse-arrays

I have a list `bdrs` of `SparseArray`s, which represent the boundary matrices of a chain complex $R^{d_0}\overset{\partial_1}{\longleftarrow}R^{d_1}\longleftarrow\ldots\longleftarrow R^{d_{N-1}}\overset{\partial_N}{\longleftarrow}R^{d_N}$ over $R\!\in\!\{\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}_p\}$. I store this data as $d_0,\ldots,d_N$=`dims`, $N$=`dim`, $R$=`p`$\!\in\!\{$`"Z",0,p`$\}$. Typically, $\partial_k$ has dimensions $10^6\!\times\!10^6$ and density $10^{-5}$. See [**this**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_Row_Storage) or [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) or [**this**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/what-are-sparsearray-properties-how-and-when-should-they-be-used) link, to understand how SparseArray stores data.

---

> For $k=1,\ldots,N$, I wish to **(a)** compute a sequence
>   `Mm`=$M_1,\ldots,M_N$, in which $M_k$ is the set of all *invertible
>   entries* in $\partial_k$, that have *zeros left of them* (in their
>   row) and *below them* (in their column). Then for every $(i,j)$-entry
>   in $M_k$, I wish to **(b)** delete it from $\partial_k$, and delete the
>   $i$-column from $\partial_{k-1}$ and $j$-row from $\partial_{k+1}$.

---

First, if $R\!=\!\mathbb{Z}_p$ I mod out the entries, then delete all zero entries, and sort the rest of the entries:

```
If[p!="Z" && p!=0, bdrs=Mod[bdrs,p]];
bdrs = Table[SparseArray[Sort@ArrayRules@bdrs[[k]],dims[[k;;k+1]]], {k,dim}];
```

### Attempt 1:

Note that some $d_k$ may be $0$. The construction is done by

```
Mm = DeleteCases[ Table[
      i=bdrs[[k,All,j]]["NonzeroPositions"][[-1,1]]; w=bdrs[[k,i,j]];   
      If[bdrs[[k,i]]["NonzeroPositions"][[1,1]]==j && If[p=="Z", w^2==1, True], 
       bdrs[[k,i,j]]=0;  {i,j}->w, ""], 
      {k,dim}, {j, If[dims[[k]]*dims[[k+1]]==0, {}, 
        DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@bdrs[[k]]["ColumnIndices"]]}], "",2];
```

or

```
Mm = DeleteCases[ Table[ {i,j}=e; w=bdrs[[k,i,j]]; 
    If[bdrs[[k,All,j]]["NonzeroPositions"][[-1]]=={i} && If[p=="Z", w^2==1, True],
     bdrs[[k,i,j]]=0;  {i,j}->w, ""], 
    {k,dim}, {e, If[dims[[k]]*dims[[k+1]]==0, {}, 
      First/@ GatherBy[bdrs[[k]]["NonzeroPositions"], First]]}], "",2];
```

and then deletion of rows/columns:

```
Do[ If[1<k,   bdrs[[k-1, All, #[[1,1]]&/@Mm[[k]] ]] = 0];   
    If[k<dim, bdrs[[k+1, #[[1,2]]&/@Mm[[k]], All ]] = 0];, {k,dim}];
```

Both constructions (a) are awfully slow on large matrices, but (b) is really fast.

### Attempt 2:

Instead of a `SparseArray`, I use an `Association` of rows and of columns.

```
rows[bdr_] := With[
  {l=GatherBy[ ArrayRules[bdr][[1;;-2]] /.({i_,j_}->w_Integer) :> {i,j,w}, First]}, 
  Association@Table[r[[1,1]]->(Rest/@r), {r,l}]]; 
mm[r_,c_] := Module[{j,w}, Association@ DeleteCases[ Table[ {j,w}=r[i][[1]]; 
  If[c[j][[-1]]=={i,w} && If[p=="Z",w^2==1,True], {i,j}->w,""],{i,Keys@r}],""]];
Mm = Table[r=rows@bdrs[[k]]; c=rows@Transpose@bdrs[[k]]; mm[r,c], {k,dim}];
```

Here (a) is much faster, but if I replace each `bdrs[[k]]` with its association of rows and of columns, then achieving (b) becomes very slow (applying `DeleteCases[#,MemberQ[#[[1,1]]&/@Mm[[k]],#]&]&` to all values in the `Association`).

### Comment:

Later, I will be computing a lot sums of rows, so I need to keep either `bdrs` or rows & columns of these matrices as `Association`s.

### Examples for testing purposes:

Let us use a command, that builds up a chain complex from the faces of a simplicial complex:

```
chainComplexSC[bases_] := Module[{dim=Length@bases, dims=Length/@bases, basesk, baseskk, bdrs={}, entries, bdr, x},
   basesk = AssociationThread[bases[[1]],Range@dims[[1]]];     
   Do[ baseskk=AssociationThread[bases[[k]],Range@dims[[k]]];
    entries=Flatten[Table[{basesk[Delete[s,{{i}}]],baseskk[s]}->(-1)^(i+1),{s,Keys@baseskk},{i,k}],1];
    AppendTo[bdrs, SparseArray[entries, dims[[k-1;;k]]]]; 
   basesk=baseskk; Clear[baseskk];, {k,2,dim}]; bdrs];
sCxSimplices[facets_,k_] := ParallelCombine[ DeleteDuplicates@
   Flatten[Table[Subsets[s,{k}],{s,#}],1]&, facets,Union,Method->"CoarsestGrained"];
```

Let us create the $m\!\times\!n$ [chessboard complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex):

```
m = 4; 
n = 4; 
facets = FindClique[GraphComplement@LineGraph@CompleteGraph[{m, n}], Infinity, All];
dim = Max[Length /@ facets];
bases = Table[sCxSimplices[facets, k + 1], {k, 0, dim - 1}];
dims = Length /@ bases;
bdrs = chainComplexSC[bases];
```

A good testing example is $m\!=\!8, n\!=\!9$, which has the f-vector  `dims`=$72, 2016, 28224, 211680, 846720, 1693440, 1451520, 362880$.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you provided an example of such a complex for testing purposes.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I find this problem very interesting and tried to start right away. This problem is simply to complex to attack it without thourough testing and constructing good test cases is too time consuming. E.g. it took me quite a while to realize that instead of two sorts of entries (zeroes and nonzeroes) we need three (zeroes, noninvertible nonzeroes, and invertible nonzeroes) and that was kind of frustrating. So a potential example should feature also noninvertible nonzeroes.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You are right, I added the construction of test examples. Since it is the chain complex of a simplicial complex, it has only entries $0,\pm1$. For now, let us focus on this case (where all nonzero entries are invertible). If needed, one can replace all $-1$ entries with $2$ to get an example with nonunit entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *might* solve problem (a). You have to preprocess the input matrix `A` such that it has `1` at positions where the original matrix `bdrs[[k]]` had an invertible element and `-1` at positions where the original matrix had a noninvertible nonzero element.

Here is a test matrix:

```
n = 10000;
m = 10000;
nedges = 4000000;
A = SparseArray`SparseArraySort@SparseArray[
    Transpose[{
       RandomInteger[{1, m}, nedges],
       RandomInteger[{1, n}, nedges]
       }] -> RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, nedges],
    {m, n}];
```

This computes the set of pairs `(i,j}` as described by OP; it runs through in about a quarter of a second.

```
M = A \[Function] Module[{Ainv, At, rowswithinv, firstinvcolumns, firstnonzerocolumns, rowswithleadinginv, leadinginvcols, lastnonzerorows},
   Ainv = SparseArray[Clip[A, {0, 1}]];
   rowswithinv = Random`Private`PositionsOf[Unitize[Differences[Ainv["RowPointers"]]], 1];
   If[Length[rowswithinv] > 0,
    firstinvcolumns = Flatten[Ainv["ColumnIndices"][[Ainv["RowPointers"][[rowswithinv]] + 1]]];
    firstnonzerocolumns = Flatten[A["ColumnIndices"][[A["RowPointers"][[rowswithinv]] + 1]]];
    With[{picker = Random`Private`PositionsOf[UnitStep[firstnonzerocolumns - firstinvcolumns], 1]},
     rowswithleadinginv = rowswithinv[[picker]];
     leadinginvcols = firstinvcolumns[[picker]];
     ];
    If[Length[leadinginvcols] > 0,
     At = Transpose[A[[All, leadinginvcols]]];
     lastnonzerorows = Flatten[At["ColumnIndices"][[At["RowPointers"][[2 ;; -1]]]]];
     With[{picker = Random`Private`PositionsOf[UnitStep[rowswithleadinginv - lastnonzerorows], 1]},
      Transpose[{
        rowswithleadinginv[[picker]],
        leadinginvcols[[picker]]
        }]
      ]
     ,
     {}
     ]
    ,
    {}
    ]
   ];
```

Now,

```
 M[A]; // AbsoluteTiming //First
```

> 0.227727

The only ingredients of measureable costs are the lines

```
Ainv = SparseArray[Clip[A, {0, 1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.138703

and

```
At = Transpose[A[[All, leadinginvcols]]];
```

which costs about `0.096315` seconds.

However, I have not tested the implementation thoroughly, yet.

## Side Remark

You might find this interesting. Your example can be generated much quicker by using Szabolcs' package [`` "IGraphM`" ``](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) along with the following code:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
facets = IGCliques[GraphComplement@LineGraph@CompleteGraph[{m, n}]];
bases = Sort@*Developer`ToPackedArray /@ GatherBy[facets, Length];
dims = Length /@ bases;
```

Moreover, the following function might be faster at generating the boundary operators:

```
chainComplexSC2[bases_] := 
  Module[{dim, dims, basesk, baseskk, bdrs = {}, entries, bdr, x, a, cf},
   dim = Length@bases;
   dims = Length /@ bases;
   cf = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
     Table[Delete[list, i], {i, 1, Length[list]}],
     CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True
     ];
   basesk = AssociationThread[bases[[1]], Range@dims[[1]]];
   Do[
    baseskk = AssociationThread[bases[[k]], Range@dims[[k]]];
    a = SparseArray[
      Rule[
       Transpose[{
         Lookup[basesk, Flatten[cf[Keys@baseskk], 1]],
         Flatten[Transpose@ConstantArray[Range[dims[[k]]], k]]
         }],
       Flatten[ConstantArray[(-1)^Range[2, k + 1], dims[[k]]]]
       ],
      dims[[k - 1 ;; k]]
      ];
    AppendTo[bdrs, a];
    basesk = baseskk;
    Clear[baseskk];,
    {k, 2, dim}];
   bdrs
   ];
```

Comment: Was the family of examples that I provided of any help to you?

Comment: Oh, I've been quite busy in the last couple of days. Was the code that I provided of any help to you?

Comment: Umm, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but for `A=SparseArray[{{2,3}->7,{5,1}->1,{4,2}->-1,{5,5}->-1},{5,5}];` your `M` returns `{{2,3},{5,1}}` instead of `{{5,1}->1,{4,2}->-1}`. Also, what does `SparseArray\`SparseArraySort@SparseArray[...]` do? Sorts the entries lexicographically? Is this better than `SparseArray[Sort@...]`?

Comment: ``SparseArray`SparseArraySort`` is totally different from `SparseArray[Sort@...]`; it enforces that the internal representation of the sparse array is conforming to [CRS standard](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_Row_Storage). This standard is heavily used in the posted piece of code, so the input matrix must be conforming. Secondly, I said that you have to preproces your input matrix: Only entries `0`, `-1`, and `1` are allowed: `1` stands for an invertible nonzero entry and `-1` for a noninvertible nonzero entry.

Comment: Ahaa, ok now it works correctly, and *very* fast! I preprocessed the matrix (over $\mathbb{Z}$) with `f[w_] := Which[w==0,0,w^2==1,1,True,-1]; SetAttributes[f,Listable]; A=f@A;`, but now this piece of code uses up 85% of the whole running time. Is there a better way?

Comment: In that case, `Clip[A^2, {0, 1}, {-1, -1}]` should work also much faster...

Comment: I wanted to let you know that your solutions work extremely efficiently. By providing such code, you're doing me and the community a big favour, as well as promoting Mathematica, so thank you! :D Also, thank you for the `IGraphM` package; it's a shame I can't upvote your answer more times. I might have some questions later on, after I've pondered on the code long enough...

Comment: I am glad to hear that this has been of help to you!

Comment: I think instead of `SparseArray`SparseArraySort[..]` you could just use `SparseArray` again, e.g., ``SparseArray`SparseArraySort@SparseArray[...]``.

Comment: @CarlWoll I see, you're right. Actually, I had presumed that `SparseArray` were implemented as identity operator on `SparseArray`s.  Nonetheless, ``SparseArray`SparseArraySort`` has the advantage that it is self-documenting and `SparseArray@*SparseArray` is not--a later version of mine could attempt to remove the seemingly redundant `SparseArray` and break the code.

Comment: Note that `SparseArray @* SparseArray` both sorts and removes background elements, while ``SparseArray`SparseArraySort `` only sorts. You may or may not want this behavior.

Comment: @CarlWoll @HenrikSchumacher Does transposing or permuting rows/cols (e.g. `a[[{3,1,2,5,4}]]`) mess up the CSR/CSC structure? After those operations, do we need to apply `SparseArray @* SparseArray@a` or `SparseArray`SparseArraySort` again?

Comment: Apparently, that is not necessary: `a = IdentityMatrix[10, SparseArray]; SparseArray`SparseArraySortedQ[
 a[[{3, 1, 2, 5, 4}]]]` returns `True`, hence the new array is sorted already.

Comment: How come `a=SparseArray[{{1,4}->14,{1,2}->12},{2,5}]; SparseArray`SparseArraySortedQ@a` returns True, even though `a["NonzeroValues"]`  returns `{14,12}`? I'm running MMA11.3. Also, given `a`, is just `a=SparseArray@a;` enough to make sure `a` is without zeros and in CSR format?

Comment: Huh. That's indeed shocking. Hm. I don't know what to say about that...