# Performing sparse sum on Mathematica

Tags: summation

I want to evaluate a sum in Mathematica of the form

`Sum[g[[i,j,k,l,m,n]] x g[[o,p,q,r,s,t]] x (complicated function of the indices i,j etc), {i,0,3}, {j,0,3}, {k,0,3}, {l,0,3}, {m,0,3}, {n,0,3}, {o,0,3}, {p,0,3}, {q,0,3}, {r,0,3}, {s,0,3}, {t,0,3}]`

But all these indices range from 0 to 3, so the total number of cases to sum over is 4^12, which will take an unforgiving amount of time. However, barely any elements of the array g[[i,j,k,l,m,n]] are nonzero -- there are probably around 8 nonzero entries -- so I would like to restrict the sum over {i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t} to precisely those combinations of indices for which both factors of g are nonzero.

I can't find a way to do this for summation over multiple indices, where the allowed index choices are particular combinations of {i,j,k,l,m,n} as opposed to specific values of each particular index. Any help appreciated!

Comment: tried [SparseArray](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) and the property `"NonzeroPositions"`? See also: [What are SparseArray Properties? How and when should they be used?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83721/125)

Comment: @kglr those properties are now documented and this one is referred to as `"ExplicitPositions"`. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html#1948657

Comment: Thank you very much @GregHurst (didn't know about the v13.0 update).

Comment: @kglr How does that help me evaluate this sum? I understand that I can use NonzeroPositions to determine which elements of my array g are nonzero, but how do I then restrict the sum to only these values of the indices?

Comment: pseudo spin, by `g[[i,j,k,l,m,n]] x g[[o,p,q,r,s,t]] x ...`  did you mean `g[[i,j,k,l,m,n]] + g[[o,p,q,r,s,t]] + ...`?

Comment: @kglr No, terribly sorry -- I meant that I have a product of three quantities, which are functions of 12 indices, and I want to sum over those indices. I have edited my question to make this clearer!!

Comment: @pseudospin is there a condition that determines which elements are zero based on the symmetries of the indices? it was not clear to me from the OP that's why I am asking

Comment: one possible way: check if this gives what you need: `g = SparseArray[g]; nzp = s["NonzeroPositions"];
Sum[s[[## & @@ i]] s[[## & @@ j]] FOO[i, j], {i, nzp}, {j, nzp}]`

Comment: @kcr Not as far as I can tell -- there possibly is but it would be hard to figure it out

Comment: `Total[s[[## & @@ #]] s[[## & @@ #2]] FOO[##] & @@@ Tuples[nzp, 2]]` should give the same result.

Comment: please note that mathematica indices start at 1 (not at 0).

Comment: @kglr Using this on a test case, I think this works fine! Do you want to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
complicatedFunctionOfIndices = FOO[FromDigits @ Sort @ #, FromDigits @ ReverseSort @#2]&

SeedRandom[1]
myg = RandomChoice[{3000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} -> Range[0, 5], {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}];

Dimensions[myg]
```

> ```
> {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}
> ```

```
sa = SparseArray[myg]
```

[image]

```
nonZeroPositions = sa["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3}, {1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4}, 
>  {4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4}, {4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2}}
> ```

```
nonZeroValues = sa["NonzeroValues"]
```

> ```
>  {3, 5, 3, 1, 4}
> ```

```
sum = Sum[sa[[## & @@ i]] sa[[## & @@ j]] complicatedFunctionOfIndices[i, j], 
  {i, nonZeroPositions}, {j, nonZeroPositions}]
```

[image]

As expected `sum` has 25 terms.

We get the same result using [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html):

```
total = Total[sa[[## & @@ #]] sa[[## & @@ #2]] complicatedFunctionOfIndices[##]  & @@@ 
  Tuples[nonZeroPositions, 2]];

sum == total
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Note:** Per Greg Hurt's comment above, replace `"NonzeroPositions"` with `"ExplicitPositions"` if you have version 13.0,